# application needs permissions to access to usb lights on ubuntu

Tags: usb, permissions, ubuntu-12.04

I have a server running ubuntu server 12.04 and have an application that needs access to some usb lights is there a standard device group i can add the user to, or some other way to give it permissions to all usb hardware? or at least the usb lights?

I have currently got this working by adding the user to the root group which i know is not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/postlfs/devices.html

Apparently you may be able to add the user to the usb group to enable, but that is akin to giving the user 'root' group permissions, apparently.

from the link, above:

> Fine-tuning of device attributes such as group name and permissions is
>   possible by creating extra udev rules, matching on something like
>   this. The vendor and product can be found by searching the
>   /sys/devices directory entries or using udevadm info after the device
>   has been attached. See the documentation in the current udev directory
>   of /usr/share/doc for details.

for example

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="05d8", SYSFS{idProduct}=="4002", \
GROUP:="scanner", MODE:="0660"
```

'scanner' would be the group assigned to the item above. Again, according to the post, `udevadm info` would give the vendo and product ids for above.

Comment: a little google goes a long way: https://www.google.com/search?q=changing+device+group+permissions+for+usb+device&oq=changing+device+group+permissions+for+usb+device&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8